# How to access to Win Server 2012 remote desktop via pure http/https?

Tags: http, remote-desktop, rdp, remote-desktop-services

**Context**

We have some Win Server 2012 machines hosted in Azure. We use the default RDP access to our machines. However in some client LANs RDP (out) is not enabled, and all http/https traffic controlled by a proxy. **There is absolute no way to allow RDP out.**

- We have full control over our Win Server 2012 machines,
- We have partial control over the client machines, we are local admins, but we have no control over group policy etc.
- The client machines are Win 7
- The Win Server 2012 machines are independent AD servers too, but there are no other machines in the AD except themselfs.

**Question**

How can we access the remote desktop from the client machines? What to install/configure on the Win Server 2012 and what to install/configure on the clients?

**What I've done/read so far?**

I've read about the Remote Desktopn Web Access, and tried to configure the server with that role. However I can only initiate the remote desktop in browser 
when I run the browser in the server itself got an Access Denied error message. 
**Worst:** When I try initiate the remote desktop in browser (https://server_name/rdweb) from a remote machine I have no rdp button on the page...

Comment: It's common for proxy and firewall servers to whitelist as needed.  You should have a talk with the network folks managing the proxy server to see if they will open the needed ports for the rdp access for you.

Comment: I forgot to underscore: There is absolute no way to allow RDP out. That's why the question title asks about pure http/https